# django:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pure_pagination'

Tags: django, debugging, pycharm

I used "pip install django-pure-pagination", and regiter "pure_pagination" into seetings.py.
By use "help('pure_pagination')", I can find the module.
But when I debug it on the PycharmIDE. It showes "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pure_pagination' ".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPlVZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRcfg.png)

Comment: django==2.0.1 django-pure-pagination==0.3.0
This problem is so weird. I'm a green hand on django. I don't know how to solve it.
 Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you sure if the environments in which you have installed these libraries and the environment you are running your project is same?

Comment: Django-pure-pagination==0.3.0 is based upon Django's core pagination module and is therefore compatible with the existing api. Just require the version of django is 1.7+. I used pip to install it. It works when I runserver. However, when I debugged the project on the pycharm2018.2.1, it showed the wrong. Then I directly put the source code into the project. And It became normal. But I find no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to configure your pycharm to for your virtual environment.

Copy pasted from Pycharm [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html):

> 2. In the Project Interpreter page, click [image]  and select Add.
> 3. In the left-hand pane of the Add Python Interpreter dialog box, select Virtualenv Environment. The following actions depend on whether
>    the virtual environment existed before.
> 4. If Existing environment is selected:
>
>    1. Specify the required interpreter: use the drop-down list, or click Select an interpreter and find one in your file system.
>    2. Select the check-box Make available to all projects, if needed.
> 5. Click OK to complete the task.

Comment: The project was based on a virtual environment all the time. Thank you for your detailed advice.